# Semantic UI dropdowns: prevent onchange event from firing when selected option is changed programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

When you change selected value of a dropdown with a change event handler programmatically in standard HTML, that event is not fired.  For example, if I do:

```
document.getElementById("my_select").value = "foo";
```

the onchange event handler of the dropdown is not executed (it only responds to user-initiated events).

I am converting all dropdowns in my code to Semantic UI (which is a great library, BTW).  However, the problem is that now the onchange event fires regardless of whether the change was initiated by user interaction or by some JS function.

So, when I do this:

```
$('#my_select').dropdown('set selected', 'foo');
```

the onchange event is fired.

Here is the fiddle that shows both behaviors:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kasafarov/jvhgkwst/21/)**

So, my questions are:

- Is there another way (other than "set selected") to select one of the options in a dropdown that will not fire onchange event?
- If not, is there a way to prevent the event from firing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the behaviour you desire you need to trick the system into thinking you've already selected the option you wish you select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();

 $('#change_button').click( function() {
    //set the value to the value you want
  $('#semantic_select')[0].value='3';
    //now use the semantic ui function
  $('#semantic_select').dropdown('set selected', '3');

 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<select id="semantic_select" class="ui dropdown" onchange="alert('Semantic Changed')">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" /><br /><br />
```

By setting the value, *then* calling the `dropdown` function the system thinks you've already selected the value you're setting, so the change event doesn't fire.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not update the dropdown either.  The original select element gets updated, but it is hidden by Semantic UI.  The visible dropdown created by Semantic UI does not show the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I am overlooking something, but it does not work for me.  You are right - the event handler is not fired, but the dropdown remains unchanged, still showing blank value.  So, I guess if there was a way to update Semantic UI dropdown to match the value of corresponding hidden select element, that would solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, I had it working simply when the javascript finished loading. I can see in your updated fiddle it doens't work..

Comment: @KirillSafarov I have updated my code to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem I would split it in two parts :

A part for the setValue behaviour :

```
$('#semantic_select').dropdown('set value', 3)
```

And a part for the setText behaviour :

```
$('#semantic_select').dropdown('set text', 'three')
```

So that this will both update text and value.

Comment: I've tried this, but "set value" still fires the event handler.  I've updated the Fiddle to show that it does not work. either.

Answer (score 0):

This change for fomantic-ui resolves the problem:
https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/pull/1683.

Just set 'preventChangeTrigger' parameter to true for the 'set selected' behavior.